# Difference Between Class Properties and Function Prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I like to learn the difference between Class Property and Prototype in Javascript what I mean is shown in the code :

```
function Rectangle(x, y) {
    this.width = x;
    this.height = y;
}

Rectangle.UNIT = new Rectangle(1, 1);

Rectangle.prototype.UNIT = new Rectangle(1, 1);
```

The thing I know is prototype is working like inherit object which means UNIT will be shown all the instances from now on but  `Rectangle.UNIT = new Rectangle(1, 1);` code doesn't do the same thing ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Rectangle.UNIT` is a **static** class property. It can only ever be accessed on the Rectangle class object. It won't be accessible on any instances of Rectangle.

`Rectangle.prototype.UNIT` is a prototype property and can be accessed on instances of Rectangle.

If you make a class `Square` that inherits from `Rectangle`, any instances of `Square` **will share** the same prototype property, but **not** any static class properties.

You may find these articles helpful (though maybe a little obscure):

- http://phrogz.net/JS/Classes/OOPinJS.html
- http://phrogz.net/JS/Classes/OOPinJS2.html
- http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little bit more please : "Static properties can vary between classes that share a given prototype inheritance chain."

Answer (score 2):

[Class-Based vs. Prototype-Based Languages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Class-based_vs._prototype-based_languages) @ Mozilla Developer Center. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle.UNIT is like a class static member, whereas Rectangle.prototype.UNIT is a local member. Looks like you want Rectangle.UNIT in your case, because you only need one static instance of the object.