# ConstructorFunc.property vs ConstructorFunc.prototype.property

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any difference between the below declarations?

**declaration 1**:

```
someName.test1 = function() {alert("test1")}
```

**declaration 2**:

```
someName.protoype.test2 = function() {alert("test2")}
```

Duplicate of [Difference Between Class Properties and Function Prototype in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355561/difference-between-class-properties-and-function-prototype-in-javascript)

Comment: The latter will throw an error if `prototype` is not an object. You cannot get a proper answer if you don't explain what `someName` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference:

```
someName.test1 = function() {alert("test1")}
```

adds this function to the object (or class) `someName`.

```
someName.protoype.test2 = function() {alert("test2")}
```

adds this function to *all instances* of class `someName`

---

For a real example, look at this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames = function(obj)  { ... };
```

which is just a function *namespaced* into the `Object` class, taking the object of interest as its first parameter, whereas if it had been written:

```
Object.prototype.getOwnPropertyNames = function() { ... };
```

Then *every* `Object` would have that method and it would be used like this:

```
obj.getOwnPropertyNames();
```

[but don't do that, since adding methods to the `Object` prototype is frowned upon!]

Comment: ok thxs, what is the right way of invoking test2? Is it someName.test2() or instanceOfsomeName.test2()?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In case you are associating test2 to the entire prototype chain of somename object.So its basically like you are here adding a method to a class which is available to all instances of someName. In case one it just gets added to that particular object.

This may be a little confusing intially but if you take it in terms that if you want to add a property or method to all instances of a class (someName) than you will use prototype. And if you want to just add it to a single object(someName) than you will use the first Step.